# Enter key is not working while NVDA is reading the bootstrap modal content, Last button is getting clicked when the complete content is read

Tags: javascript, accessibility, uiaccessibility, nvda

When the modal is shown to the user and focus is set on the close button using 'shown.bs.modal'. NVDA reads the overview first. At that time enter key is working and closing the modal. **But when NVDA reads the content using HTML syntax** e.g (`<h2> Something </h2>` as **heading level 2 something**) **then enter key is not working**. Any of the **keyup, keydown and keypress** event is not getting triggered. Only the escape key is working at the time to close the modal or click the 'close' button.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don’t understand. A `<h2>` is not an interactive element, cannot be focussed and not be interacted with. So you are reading the dialog not in interaction mode, I guess?

Comment: I added the basic Bootstrap example to your question. Does the modal in the snippet demonstrate your issue?